# Possible to do Firebase social login + still have option to instead use manual email/password for creating/auth-ing accounts?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm thinking about implementing social authentication for an React app I want to create.
I see Firebase handles alot of that work for you for Google/Twitter/FB/GitHub auth.
But i still want to have an option to offer a manual signup (and for those users offer a manual login). 
Is that possible? Like will Firebase store/auth manual users via their Authentication system? Or i need to have a separate auth system for that (with my own database/auth check outside of Firebase)?

I'm very new to this so just thought I'd ask. Some links to some React articles would be great. I only saw ones that implement social but not social+manual authentication (preferably via Firebase to cover all social logins vs manually setting each OAUTH system).
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single user account in Firebase Authentication can be linked with multiple providers. You can link those providers together after the user signs in with them.

For more on this, see the [Firebase documentation on account linking](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking). From there:

> You can allow users to sign in to your app using multiple authentication providers by linking auth provider credentials to an existing user account. Users are identifiable by the same Firebase user ID regardless of the authentication provider they used to sign in. For example, a user who signed in with a password can link a Google account and sign in with either method in the future. Or, an anonymous user can link a Facebook account and then, later, sign in with Facebook to continue using your app.

Comment: Hey, I don't think this is the answer Im looking for... I realize you can link different social accounts like that (ive seen that in action on a few websites and think that feature is cool). Im looking for manually signing up old school with an email/password as an option. I'm just if they can exist side-by-side with social auth options and *within* Firebase Authentication (instead of implementing it myself in my DB, i thought maybe Firebase Auth offers a 'manual option'). Maybe delete your answer as its off-topic from the question and re-answer the question if think know a solution.

Comment: or 'Passport' which alot of people use for Social login in react apps... maybe that has an email option. not sure. i'll prob research later this weekend

Comment: Allowing a user to sign in with email+password *and* also with a social provider is precisely a use-case that Firebase Authentication account linking is for. If you're having a hard time making it work, update your question to show what you've tried.

Comment: So does Firebase Auth have a mechanism to store&auth custom user credentials (be4 pretend the future date where the user may set up account-linking to social accounts, like this is the 1st time they using app and opt for the custom manual email/user option)?

Comment: Thanks Frank, did a little research.. i do see Firebase Auth heavily mentions regular 'Email and password based authentication' in addition to 'Federated identity provider integration' aka social login. I didn't know it could handle the regular login as well. I'll accept yours as the answer (can you just maybe mention that main docs page of Firebase Auth states it can handle both?).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible to make the authentication using firebase. Few dependencies you need to have in mind like, "react-native-firebase", for google sign-in "react-native-google-signin"

[For Checking with Provider refer here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking)
[Android Setup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

I am sharing sample code for Google Sign-in:

```
    import { GoogleSignin } from 'react-native-google-signin';
    import firebase from 'react-native-firebase'
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: firebaseConfigg.API_KEY,
      authDomain: firebaseConfigg.AUTH_DOMAIN,
      databaseURL: firebaseConfigg.DATABASE_URL,
      projectId: firebaseConfigg.PROJECT_ID,
      storageBucket: firebaseConfigg.STORAGE_BUCKET,
      messagingSenderId: firebaseConfigg.GCM_SENDER_ID
    };

    if (!firebase.apps.length) {
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    }

   login = async() => {
    await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices({ autoResolve: true });
          const sigin = await GoogleSignin.configure({
            iosClientId: '',
            forceConsentPrompt: true,
            scopes: ['profile', 'email']
          }).then(async (success) => {
            if (success) {
                GoogleSignin.signIn().then((data) => {
                console.log("--->> ", data);
                  const credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(data.idToken, data.accessToken);
                  firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential).catch((error) => {
                  });
                })
            }
          })
    }
```

Comment: i don't *think* this is the answer im looking for. This is just for Google Auth. Im looking for using Firebase to do manual auth (user has to enter their own email and password... not link to Google/Facebook). If misunderstood the question, please delete the answer.